# Parallax plugin causing gap in background of element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this section below:

```
<section class="contact-info">

</section>
```

It has the following CSS:

```
.contact-info {
  background: url(http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 1500px 446px;
  background-size: 1500px 446px;
  padding: 2em 0;
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
  .contact-info {
    -webkit-background-size: 2000px 595px;
    background-size: 2000px 595px;
  }
}
```

and I have used a parallax plugin and initialized it like so:

```
$('.contact-info').parallax("50%", 0.7);
```

Now when I scroll or come to the section There is a big gap, the background images does not cover the entire height of the div ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/xcq80kdk/)).

I saw a [similar issue here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/694), but the solution really didn't work.

Comment: the gap is caused by your content being bigger than the image, bigger image = no gap  http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/xcq80kdk/3/

Comment: @AndrewBone Thanks ! will try ur solution out